# Placing a share button over a uiwebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I have an rss app that I'm working on in xcode and the articles load up in a full screen web view. I need to place a "share" button in the navigation bar but since my uiwebview is full screen it won't show up when I run the app. I even tried cropping the top of the web view lower and placing the button there but still no luck. Here is an example of what I mean:

[image]

The share button needs to be on the right side of the navigation bar but i cannot seem to figure out how that make that work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: so a navigation bar _does_ or _does not_ show when the web view is presented?

Comment: There is one that shows when I run the app, it shows the title of the article. I used a free source code to make my rss app and the web view was done by whoever created it. But in the project it just shows a full screen web view

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, your top navigation bar seems to be missing (judging by your image). Since the nav bar is missing there is no possible way that the share button will be visible. You can do this is the IB or in your code.

For your IB you can move the view controller's 'layer's' so to speak. When you place all the elements down, your VC should look something like this:

[image]

On the left hand side we can see what subviews are at the top and which ones are at the bottom.

[image]

As we can see here that the UIWebView is at the top of the list, so it'll be at the bottom of the pile. The navigation bars are further down the list so they'll be at the top of the pile. So due to this they'll go over the UIWebView.

The other way to do this is using `insertSubview:aboveSubview:`. Fist of all you'll add your UIWebView using `addSubview:` and then add the nav bar using `insertSubview:aboveSubview:` and finally you'll add your button the someway as you did for the nav bar, but this time you'll be adding the button above the nav bar not the web view.

My best guess is that your forgetting to add another navigation bar to the top of the screen. Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply! I used a free source code to make my project and the web view was already done. I will try your suggestion as soon as I can and I'll update you. Thanks!